# Laravel 5, Form validation being bypassed by spam

Tags: laravel-5

please be gentle on me.

I have a Laravel 5.8 based website which has a html form.  The form responses are handled by a controller which emails a copy of the data to us and also saves the data in a mysql database after having been validated by the controller. It all works lovely, however....

The thing is, we are receiving a number of responses (which follow a similar pattern of submitted values) that should be rejected by the validation. in fact, if I copy and paste the values from one of these email responses into the form on the website and submit it, it does fail validation.

This leads me to conclude that somehow data is being submitted in a way that bypasses the validation part of the controller.

I have scoured the internet and can find nothing that relates to the fault I'm seeing. Which leads me to the conclusion that it's definitely something I've done wrong.

The upshot is that I have spent days going round in circles trying this and tweaking that but nothing has made a difference so far I have no idea where to go with this and I'm hoping that some of you clever people could at least point me in the direction of a list of likely things to check.

As I said previously the site functions fine and if I use the forms on the site, validation works. Therefore I haven't included any code. I know it's all a bit vague and if I can provide any further information please shout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO it's highly unlikely that spammers can circumvent Laravel validation except if they have access to your server. Which validations aren't failing? And since it's mails, are you absolutely sure they come from that form? You can try changing the mail slightly and see if the spam changes as well.

Comment: That's weird.. Which specific validations aren't failing?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your response. I'm with you in that I suspect it might be server security related rather than a Laravel issue. Presumably if it was a Laravel issue the interweb would be littered with similar queries. I have changed the email template slightly and those changes are showing in the spam responses received which makes me fairly certain that they are being generated by my web server, the responses are also being stored in the database as per the controller's intended functionality. Thanks again

Comment: In response to your second question, None of my validation rules fail when I submit the form from the website using acceptable values.  All validation rules fail as expected when 'illegal' data is submitted from the form.  However the spammers are able to submit data that would normally fail validation.

Comment: I meant the validation rules that fail if you manually submit the spam values (and don't seem to fail for the spammers). It might be, for example, that they submit spaces which counts as not empty (hence the `required` rule passes) but those are stripped from the email.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  primarily there are two rules that should fail.  We have a phone number input that has to st 01, 02 or 07 and a rule on the message body that won't allow the text to contain http.  The spammers are submintinng phone numbers that always start 8.... and are able to post website links in the the message body.

Comment: OK, the number input is really weird.. The only thing I can think of for the links is maybe a different encoding or adding non-printed characters. Does the form also submit if you insert spam data from the database (instead of the mail)?

Comment: I Just copied and pasted the data from the database (using phpmyadmin) and the website rejected the data for having the wrong phone number format and containing illegal characters in the body

Comment: I.E. validation is doing what it should be

Comment: I Think I may have found the cause - and I was right, it was my stupidity.  I had created another controller (somewhere in the dim distant past) that submitted data and used the same email template. I am such a do-nut sometimes.  really sorry for wasting your time but thank you so much, I really appreciate your support.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it's fixed